# what is the best software to draw ERD for a mysql database for windows

Tags: mysql, windows, erd

What is the best software to draw ERD in Windows for a MySQL database.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use staruml

http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/modules.php

http://staruml.sourceforge.net/docs/StarUML_5.0_Developer_Guide.pdf (see chapter 10 for instruction on creating ER, and installing ER module)

Comment: I've used this before and can also highly recommend it

Comment: Star UML has been great. Also PSQL Extension https://github.com/adrianandrei-ca/staruml-postgresql

Answer (score 2):

I've been using MySQL Workbench for a couple of months now (the community version) and I am very pleased with the result.

MySQL Workbench it is based on DBDesigner4 which was another great tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a decent web browser on Windows, go try [SchemaBank](http://schemabank.com). They have native support for MySQL.

Comment: For others that see this, SchemaBank.com now redirects to an adware site.

Answer (score 1):

I've used an **open-source** Java-based tool called [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) recently and it worked very well.

> SchemaSpy analyzes schema metadata, letting you click through the hierarchy of tables' parent/child relationships. Works with just about any RDBMS that supports JDBC (Oracle/MySQL/DB2/SQL Server/PostgreSQL/Sybase/etc). Also identifies common anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

Visio has a Database Model Diagram template that can be used to draw [Entity-Relation Diagrams](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HP010181611033.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Toad Data Modeler](http://www.toadsoft.com/toaddm/toad_data_modeler.htm) before with good results.