# Generate ERD from SQLyog

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, sqlyog

is there a way for me to generate an Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) from SQLyog? or if not, from PHPmyAdmin of XAMPP? thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com) has this feature- Schema designer, which is a visual interface where tables and table structures can be defined, displayed and manipulated. But Schema Designer is not a full featured ERD diagramming tool. I don't think it is possible to generate from PHPMyAdmin either. You could look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283505/what-is-the-best-software-to-draw-erd-for-a-mysql-database-for-windows).

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in SQLyog. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. This will open the Schema Designer. It's not a very good designer but it works well for simple ERDs.

Answer (score 1):

SQLYog has a Schema Designer option <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>D</kbd> which opens a Schema Designer window.

Right click inside Schema Designer canvas to get small window, select checkbox **add tables** ( Select all checkboxes if you want all of them on Canvas)

Click **Add** to get ER diagram of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

**Note:** It's only for full version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can generate ERD with PHPMyAdmin. PHPMyadmin added this functionality from version 3.4

detail step to generate ERD : http://goo.gl/0z3vFE

You can refer to PHPMyAdmin documentation for more info: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#pmadb